# Remove contents of this parent

Tags: jquery, removeall

I have this HTML:

```
    <div id="hi">
    <span style="border:1px solid red;">This span should stay</span>
    <br />
    this should be removed
</div>
```

I would like to remove everything(*) inside div#hi that is not span:

This doesn't seem to work:

```
 $('#hi').not('span').remove();
```

It removes evertthing. What else can I try?

[JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/BaLAb/5/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#hi').contents().filter(function(){
     return this.localName !== 'span';
}).remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TUuQ9/

Comment: @undefined why it wont works with the span but works with localName

Comment: Do you perhaps have any idea why this doesn't work `$('span').parent()` [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BaLAb/7/)

Comment: @sasi Because in the OP code, `not` filters the selected element which is `#hi` element not it's contents, also jQuery selectors do not select textNodes that's why `.contents()` is used.

Comment: @Youss What should happen in your fiddle?

Comment: @undefined Hi, I never heard of localName, I'm trying to replace `!== 'span';` because Im working with variables/ID's and Classes. Can you please help me out, maybe modify the code a bit so that I can pass Jquery variables?

Comment: @Youss Hi, `localName` is a property of the DOM Element Object it returns name of the `tagName` in lowercase, if you want to use IDs and classes `localName` is not what you want, please provide a demo and let me know what exactly should  be selected.

Comment: Ok, let say I have a var like this `var MyVar = $('span');` How do I set this var? Because this doesn't work `return this.localName !== 'MyVar';` I altered the demo [over here](http://jsfiddle.net/TUuQ9/1/)

Comment: I also just read that IE8 does not support localName, I really would like to include IE8, lots of people are still using it

Comment: @Youss I have updated your fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/TUuQ9/2/, Regarding IE8 instead of the `localName` use `tagName` but name of the tagName should be uppercase, ie, `return this.tagName !== 'SPAN';`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this with `.clone()`:

```
$cln = $('#hi').find('span').clone();
$('#hi').html($cln);
```

#### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BaLAb/8/)